# Where is Sympy's LUsolve defined?

Tags: sympy

I am using Sympy's LUsolve for my research and would like to check the implementation myself. But, I could not find the location the function is defined.

At first, I thought it is in solvers.py (https://github.com/sympy/sympy/blob/46e00feeef5204d896a2fbec65390bd4145c3902/sympy/solvers/solvers.py#L2357-L2394), but it seems like it (solve_linear_system_LU) uses a method of matrix object (A.LU_solve). But when I checked the matrix object, it uses a function defined in solvers.py, so I am confused. Could anyone have an insight?

Comment: https://github.com/sympy/sympy/blob/d95d4798b21a76d0f22ac265d3a0daca20baeb12/sympy/matrices/solvers.py#L309

Comment: Thank you! It makes sense.